# Crash when calling CGImageDestinationFinalize with large photo

Tags: cocoa-touch

In the code below I am crashing on the CGImageDestinationFinalize() line. The CGImage is a large JPG photo. It works fine if I use a smaller JPG. But anything over 10MB crashes on the device with "out of memory".

I think the CGImageDestination* methods are streaming the write but I must be doing something wrong that is retaining the data.

Is there another API call I should use when writing large JPGs?

```
BOOL SKImageWriteToDisk(CGImageRef image, NSURL *url, SKImageProfile profile, CGFloat dpi)
{
    CFStringRef type = profile == SKmageProfileCompressed ? kUTTypeJPEG : kUTTypePNG;
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, type, 1, NULL);
    if (!destination) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *properties =
    [@{
        (id) kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight: @(dpi),
        (id) kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth: @(dpi)
    } mutableCopy];
    if (profile == SKImageProfileCompressed) {
        properties[(id) kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality] = @(0.8f);
    }
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)properties);
    BOOL finalizeSuccess = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination); // crash!
    CFRelease(destination);
    return finalizeSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Faced with the same issue. I think it is huge memory bug in Apple's library.